# Allow custom MIME type download - Selenium GeckoDriver preferences

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, jupyter-notebook, geckodriver

I am trying to download Jupyter Notebook files (extension `x-ipynb+json`) in a Selenium test using Firefox. I'm using the `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` preference to download other MIME types files without the popup:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                       "text/html, image/png," # ...others
                      )
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Trying to obtain the same behavior for the Jupyter notebooks, I joined `application/x-ipynb+json` according to [this](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/mimetype.html).

I have verified downloading manually, this is the right `MIME` type. It doesn't seem to work.

Configurations I'm using :

> Python 2.7.15rc1
>
> pytest-3.6.1
>
> selenium 3.8.0
>
> geckodriver 0.21.0